# SQL Result has been summed twice

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, group-by, cross-apply

I am currently dealing with a view that selects and joins data from about 6 tables. I group by team but i am using cross apply to some rows even further. All of this code works apart from the fact to group the columns further i have to SUM them again. This gives me a result that is twice as large because its being summed before the view and then i have to sum again to be able to group it.

One method ive got which gives me the result i want is to divide the sum by 2

e.g.

```
    SUM(Profit)/2
```

However, i dont believe this is the best method.

I would originally just group the columns before they get to the view but the columns are being retrieved from multiple different tables. Is there anyway i can incorporate a group by/cross apply in the join of the view?

```
    from [Table1] n     


    Left join [person] s
    on        s.Code = n.[Person]
```

or grouping specific columns using cross apply without having to SUM the other columns?

```
    cross apply (values
    (case when s.[Team] = 'Team 2' then 'Team 2'
    when s.[Team] = 'Team 3' then 'Team 3' ELSE 
    n.[Person]
     END)
    ) AS S ([Name])
```

name is taking from v
team is taken from s

Comment: You have duplicates in joins. Try to find out which table gives you duplicates and decide how to avoid that

Comment: Maybe some sample data, just enough to get the double value, would help here

Comment: Impossible to help you , please provide data structures, data sample and the full query being used.

Comment: the problem is i obviously cant post any code and the view is huge so its hard to modify and i dont know how to show you an example

Comment: if i follow all the join traces, how will it know whats causing duplicates?

Comment: Do you have any primary key or unique value to count the distinct? otherwise start to count(*) adding a join step by step...